# Razor PartialViewResult yields only the partial view

Tags: ajax, razor-pages, unobtrusive

I'm using Unobtrusive Ajax with Razor. When I return a Partial View, only the partial view content returns on a **new blank page** instead of in the designated div on original page.

```
   <form method="post" data-ajax="true" asp-page-handler="Partial" data-ajax-method="post" asp-route-id="JobNum" data-ajax-success="success" data-ajax-update="#panel">
                            
                            <input type="submit"/>
                        </form>
```

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostPartialAsync(string id)
        {
            return new PartialViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "_IndexPartial",
                ViewData = this.ViewData
            };
        }
```

expecting the result to be displayed in the  with id "panel"